# Mac Mail on El Captan malfunctioning

Tags: email, macos

One draft window flashes continually on and off the screen even though I have deleted the draft from my menu on the left.

Any ideas on what's causing this and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround in mind that would benefit you more then it would hurt you. You can always use a secondary mail client like [CloudMagic](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloudmagic-email/id1059655371?mt=12), which I used for a while. I haven't used the default mailing client for at least 2 years now. CloudMagic is free on the Mac App Store and for iOS.